# SIGSEGV Java fatal error when i tried start JBOSS standalone

Tags: java, jboss, jvm, hp-ux

I can not start jboss service and i got this error log :

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>   
> SIGSEGV (11) at pc=c000000015adc5b0, pid=5164, tid=8
>   
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0) (build 1.7.0.14-jinteg_2015_08_07_03_06-b00)
>   
> Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.85-b05-jre1.7.0.14-rc1 mixed mode hp-ux-ia64 )
>   
> Problematic frame:
>    
> V  [libjvm.so+0x962f5f60]  JVM_ResolveClass+0x963292b0
>    
> Core dump written. Default location: /appsyah/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/core or core.5164

here is my java version :

> java version "1.7.0.14"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0.14-jinteg_2015_08_07_03_06-b00)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.85-b05-jre1.7.0.14-rc1, mixed mode)

and here is jvm options that i used :

> JAVA_OPTS="-Xms8G -Xmx8G   -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.modules.policy-permissions=true -Dtafj.home=/appsyah/TAFJ -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -d64 -server  -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis -XX:-TieredCompilation -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500  -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m -XX:+UseSerialGC -XX:-UseCompressedOops"

Thank you :)

Regards,

Aldi

Comment: JDK version you use is 8 years old and is no longer supported. It is known to have *many* issues. Consider updating JDK.

Comment: While I agree with the sentiment @apangin HP still supports JDK 7 (see [this page](https://h20392.www2.hpe.com/portal/swdepot/displayProductInfo.do?productNumber=HPUXJDKJRE70)), even on Itamium and will until July of 2022 according to [this doc](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docLocale=en_US&docId=emr_na-c02690385&withFrame).  Having said that it means that the original poster needs to contact HP.